# Is there any IDE available to work with Polymer?

Tags: polymer

I recently started working with polymer. I want to know any IDE that can be used to work with polymer. Could any one suggest me?

Answer (score 3):

[Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg?hl=en) added the Polymer Designer feature on .html files so you can use it even when offline. However, it's [no longer actively developed](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chromedeveditor).

I use CDE as my primary IDE for web development instead of Sublime, mostly because I can use it even on my Chromebooks (+ basic git and bower integration)

Edit: Another Plus of CDE is that it ships with a bunch of templates to start a new project using polymer

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Polymer Designer](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/).

It's pretty awesome, you can even add your own components to it. Here's the [guide](https://github.com/Polymer/designer) on how to do this.

Also, make sure you watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HKrYfrAzqFA) by Rob Dodson. He demonstrated a lot of cool things of Polymer and the Designer is one of them.

Comment: Downvoted because designer is still quite alpha, and more importantly, I don't consider it an IDE.  I think the suggestion of CDE by @smokybob is better suited to the question.

Comment: @Tom Seriously?? CDE simply embeds the designer inside it and I'm not even sure if it allows you to add custom components. His answer might be better, but mine would also HELP.

Comment: I don't agree that 'CDE simply embeds the designer'.  CDE is in developer preview, but it is still a real IDE, whereas designer is (true to its name) just a designer.  I think the designer looks great, but I think CDE is the answer to the question asked.

Comment: @Tom, if the designer is still alpha, then the designer embedded in CDE is also alpha. There are a million IDE for web development out there, but only CDE is suitable in this case because of the embedded Polymer Designer. My answer at least extends the key reason that why CDE should be considered and it doesn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: Sure, that sounds reasonable - that the inclusion of designer is what makes CDE uniquely suitable for polymer, but my down-vote wasn't meant to be a big deal or to suggest that your answer wasn't interesting info, but rather to say that your answer is not the correct answer to the question (and yet it was higher voted then the correct answer).

Comment: All of this is moot - the designer has been rewritten and no longer lives at that URL.